# Wandering motion in Unity

Tags: unity, physics

I am trying to come up with a smooth wandering motion for my game-object using Unity. What I currently doing is rotate the object by some random angle calculated every 1.5 second delay. But I am aiming getting a smooth rotation whenever it transitions to a different randomly generated angle.

Below is my script attached to my character.

```
 void Update () {
     if (canWander && (currTime + delay < Time.time)){
        changeAngle();
        currTime = Time.time;
     }
     if(canWander){
        Wander();
     }
}

private void changeAngle(){
    float prevPosY = transform.position.y;
    Vector3 waypoint = Random.insideUnitSphere + new Vector3(10,prevPosY,10);  //waypoints are generated based on random unit sphere + ( bounds of the plane they are on )
    Vector3 relative = transform.InverseTransformPoint (waypoint);
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (relative.x, relative.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.Rotate (0, angle, 0);
}

private void Wander(){
    transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * acceleration;
    if (acceleration < maxSpeed) {
        acceleration += 0.5f;       
    }
}
```

So the character wanders with newly generated random angles every time but its not a smooth transition. It suddenly transitions to the new angle and it does not feel realistic at all. What could I possibly change with my current code to make it more smooth and realistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the new angle that you want to rotate to, use that as a *target* rotation, and then in `Update()` you can continually interpolate the character's current rotation to the target rotation using [`Mathf.LerpAngle`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpAngle.html). The rotation speed variable will be an arbitrary float that controls how quickly the character moves to the target angle.

```
void Update() {
    // ...
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed), 0);
}
```